# How can I remove ID and controller from URL in codeigniter?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have the following URL:

```
https://example.com/specialty_detail/specialty/60/Radiology-Billing-Services
```

but I want the URL:

```
https://example.com/specialty/Radiology-Billing-Services
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried htaccess Rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Send request via index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
 <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;

$route['why-we'] = 'why_we/index';
$route['why-outsource'] = 'why_outsource/index';
$route['team-member/(:num)'] = 'team-member/view/$1';
$route['category/(:num)'] = 'category/index/$1';
$route['request-a-demo'] = 'contact';

$route['admin'] = 'admin/login';

Comment: Thanks for showing efforts but please add them in your question since comments are not meant to add code or samples thank you

Comment: Are you wanting to do this for _all_ URLs or just this specific URL?

Comment: This actually is not possible in a general manner. How should the rewriting engine _guess_ that numeric ID? Which you probably need to respond to the request?