# How can I hide ID and controller from URL in php codeigniter?

Tags: .htaccess, routes, codeigniter-3

I have the following URL:

https://example.com/specialty_detail/specialty/60/Radiology-Billing-Service

but I want the URL:

https://example.com/specialty/Radiology-Billing-Services

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa8Qf.png)

check image also

Comment: You asked about the same thing only three hours earlier than this already, [How can I remove ID and controller from URL in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66972386/how-can-i-remove-id-and-controller-from-url-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you call the controller normally and then load the data using ajax as below:-

```
function submitRequest(){
    
    var values = $("#form").serialize();

   
        $.ajax({
           url: '<?php echo $Server?>/trader/submitRequest',
           type: 'POST',
           data: values,
           cache:false,
           error: function() {
              console.log('Error to submit change request');
           },
           success: function(response) {
          if(response.length == 9) {
              alert(response);
             
             
             
         }
          }
        });
      }
```